# Call a command on a view model whenever any TextBox in the view changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a few views that each have several XAML `TextBox` instances. The Text property of each is bound to a value object that represents the visual data model for the view.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I have about 9 or 10 of these boxes in a form. I have a class (`ChangeModel`) that keeps track of which forms have been altered (e.g. the user has entered in a new value). The problem is the actual value object that is bound to the `TextBox.Text` property  (in the example that would be `SelectedItem.SomeValue`) can't access the `ChangeModel`.

I'd like to easily add a binding in the XML (maybe in the resources section) that will call a command in the view model whenever any `TextBox` changes. I think I can do this with a `DataTrigger` statement but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can anyone describe how to use a data trigger or any other XAML mechanism to alert the view model whenever any `TextBox` within that view is altered?

Comment: so you want to have an implicit style for textbox that uses an eventtrigger with TextChanged and an InvokeCommandTriggerAction that calls into the ViewModel? I think this might work, but I somehow think there was this limitation of not being able to have these triggers in a Style!

Comment: so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957301/applying-same-interaction-trigger-to-multiple-textboxes) might help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to that Markus Hütter said you can save a few lines of XAML and write custom behavior like this

```
public class InvokeCommandOnTextChanged : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(InvokeCommandOnTextChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(InvokeCommandOnTextChanged));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var command = this.Command;
        var param = this.CommandParameter;

        if (command != null && command.CanExecute(param))
        {
            command.Execute(param);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this behavior with your textboxes:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:InvokeCommandOnTextChanged Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```