# WPF: Handle MouseDown-Events from within a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datatemplate

I have the following Datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="demoDataTemplate" DataType="models:SomeClass">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeTextProperty}" MouseDown="{Binding HOWTO????}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I use this DataTemplate within a ListView. How do I bind the MouseDown-Event to a method within the ViewModel which is assigned to the DataContext of the ListView?

Comment: How do you define your `ViewModel`? Is it in `StaticResources` or set in code-behind?

Comment: Are you using codebehind or `MVVM` (model, view, viewmodel)?

Comment: I use MVVM. I couldn't use CodeBehind for the MouseDown-Event anyway because I want to reuse the DataTemplate on different ListViews. But I use Code-Behind to assign a viewmodel - something like listview.DataContext = new MyViewModel();

Comment: @user1130329 in that case, I recommend using `Commands`.  Here is a [wonderful article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) to get you started! You can download the source code from the article [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026) (click on downloads tab).

Comment: I like to use a custom `AttachedCommandBehavior`, which allows you to bind most Events to Commands in your `DataContext`. You can view the example code for this in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6957974/302677). In your case, don't forget to set the `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` of the binding to your `ListView` since it's `DataContext` contains your command instead of the individual items

Answer (score 1):

Create attached Property that handles the mouse click as below

```
public class MouseClick
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseLeftClickProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseLeftClick", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseClick),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CallBack));

    public static void SetMouseLeftClick(DependencyObject sender, ICommand value)
    {
        sender.SetValue(MouseLeftClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetMouseLeftClick(DependencyObject sender)
    {
        return sender.GetValue(MouseLeftClickProperty) as ICommand;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseEventParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MouseEventParameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MouseClick),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null, null));


    public static object GetMouseEventParameter(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return d.GetValue(MouseEventParameterProperty);
    }


    public static void SetMouseEventParameter(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MouseEventParameterProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                if (e.OldValue != null)
                {
                    element.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handler));
                }
                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    element.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handler), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            ICommand cmd = element.GetValue(MouseLeftClickProperty) as ICommand;
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                RoutedCommand routedCmd =cmd as RoutedCommand;
                object paramenter = element.GetValue(MouseEventParameterProperty);
                if (paramenter == null)
                {
                    paramenter = element;
                }
                if (routedCmd != null)
                {
                    if (routedCmd.CanExecute(paramenter, element))
                    {
                        routedCmd.Execute(paramenter, element);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cmd.CanExecute(paramenter))
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(paramenter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your Xmal change it as below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="demoDataTemplate" DataType="models:SomeClass">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeTextProperty}" local:MouseClick.MouseLeftClick="{Binding Click}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where local is the namespace where MouseClick class is defined and Click is the ICommand Property in the ViewModel